# Need assistance regarding showing download images as gallery

Tags: ios

In my app I am downloading images from url and saving into application documents directory. Now I want to show these downloaded images as image gallery. For image gallery I am using [fGallery](https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone), I am able to configure it and successfully pushed it on navigation controller and fGallery view is also visible but its not showing my images, I provide fGalley with images array like this

**Header File**

```
@interface myController <FGalleryViewControllerDelegate> 

@property (strong, nonatomic) FGalleryViewController *localGallery;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSMutableArray *localImages;
```

**Class File**

```
    //These are delegate methods of FGalleryViewControllerDelegate
    - (NSString*)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController*)gallery filePathForPhotoSize:(FGalleryPhotoSize)size atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
        return [localImages objectAtIndex:index];
    }

    - (NSString*)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery urlForPhotoSize:(FGalleryPhotoSize)size atIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {
        return [localImages objectAtIndex:index];
    }

    - (int)numberOfPhotosForPhotoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery
    {
        int num;

        num = [localImages count];

        return num;
    }

    - (FGalleryPhotoSourceType)photoGallery:(FGalleryViewController *)gallery sourceTypeForPhotoAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index
    {    
         return FGalleryPhotoSourceTypeLocal;
    }
    //Delegate method ends here

// My method to show gallery with my images
-(void)ShowGallery
{
    localImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];    

     NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsDir = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *dataPath = [documentsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:chatWithUser;
NSString *msgsColumn;

    //database query to fetch all images name and then
    while([results next])
    {
        msgsColumn = [results stringForColumn:@"msgs"];
        if([[[msgsColumn componentsSeparatedByString:@"."]objectAtIndex:1]isEqualToString:@"jpg"])
        {
            [localImages addObject:[dataPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:msgsColumn]];
        }
    }

    [database close];

    localGallery = [[FGalleryViewController alloc]initWithPhotoSource:self];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:localGallery animated:YES];     
}
```

For images path i used **stringByAppendingPathComponent** but I also tried **stringByAppendingString** to guide that images resides in documents directory but nothing is working.

Please assist me to figure out what is going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, and here it is

https://github.com/gdavis/FGallery-iPhone/issues/15